# Is it required to specify view_engine in express 4?

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, express-4

I am using react as my client side JS and REST API's using Express 4. Do I really need to specify the view_engine parameter? I thought I dont need any view engine coz there is no serve side rendering. I use gulp to compile all the react jsx and it generates one file(single page app) I think. All the server has to do is to just serve that static compiled JS file. I dont know why I need view engine here.

Here is the error

Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the reason behind it, but `application.js` in Express initialises the view even though it is only used within the `render` method. The `View` class itself requires, either directly or via `defaultEngine`, a name of a library to load and loads it. Although if you supply `engines` to the options it just takes it from there by the name supplied. You could potentially dodge it at that point without making any code changes to Express itself.